# How can templated code find the length of a string whose type is a template parameter, in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider this code:

```
template <typename T>
class String
{
public:
    ...
 String(T* initStr)
 {
  size_t initStrLen;
  if (initStr != NULL)
  {
   printf_s("%s\n", typeid(T) == typeid(char) ? "char" : "wchar_t");

   if (typeid(T) == typeid(char))
   {
    strlen((T*)initStr);
   }
   else if (typeid(T) == typeid(wchar_t))
   {
    wcslen((T*)initStr);
   }
  }
 }  
    ...
};
```

When I compiled the code, I got this error message:

> ...\main.cpp(32) : error C2664: 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'wchar_t *' to 'const char *'

Then I tried to use a function pointer:

```
typedef size_t (*STRLEN)(void*);
STRLEN _strlen;
_strlen = reinterpret_cast<STRLEN> (typeid(*initStr) == typeid(char) ? strlen : wcslen);
```

and again the compiler issued an error, this time:

> ...\main.cpp(28) : error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'size_t (__cdecl *)(const wchar_t *)' to 'size_t (__cdecl *)(const char *)'

My question is, how can I use the functions `strlen` and `wcslen` with templates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this e.g. by introducing a helper function as illustrated below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

size_t GetLength(const char* s) { return strlen(s); }
size_t GetLength(const wchar_t* s) { return wcslen(s); }

template <typename T>
void PrintLength(T s)
{
    std::cout << GetLength(s) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    PrintLength("abc");
    PrintLength(L"abc");
}
```

Use this helper function `GetLength` instead of `strlen` or `wcslen` and don't check the type of the argument explicitly. You can write overloads of `GetLength` for other types as well, e.g. `std::string`.

You rarely need to use `typeid` in practice and in this case it is completely inappropriate.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use if statements to control what code is instantiated for a template: all of the code in the body must work for every instantiation.

```
std::size_t strlen(wchar_t const *s) {
  return std::wcslen(s);
}

//...
String(T* initStr) {
  using std::strlen;  // bring into scope so unqualified call can find it
  std::size_t length = strlen(initStr);  // uses std::strlen or our strlen
  //...
```

You could also add an overload of your strlen for char, then you don't need the using declaration.

Answer (score 3):

You have misunderstood templates. You should not use `typeid` to determine types here, but instead use template specialisation.

Comment: Yes, but would be nice to give a coded example. vitaut used a different approach, with an overloaded function.

Comment: My first thought was a specialisation too, but here, specialisation in practice means writing 2 versions of the class, which can be done without templates at all.

Comment: Well std::basic_string uses a specialisation but not of basic_string itself but of char_traits.

Answer (score 1):

In case the OP is interested in how strings are implemented in STL, they use a whole helper class call char_traits. This is a class with nothing but static member functions, and char_traits is specialised for char and wchar_t to use the C runtime library functions like memmove.

For example you have a compare function that returns a value <0, 0 or >0. Where the type is char it can use memcmp. Where the type is wchar_t it can use the wide equivalent.

It works something like this:

```
template< typename Element >
class char_traits
{
public:
   static int compare( const Element * left, const Element * right, size_t length )
   {
       for( const Element * end = left + length; left != end; ++left )
       {
          if( left < right )
             return -1;
          else if( left > right )
              return 1;
       }
       return 0;
   }
  // other functions
};

template <> class char_traits<char> // I think this is the syntax
{
public:
   int compare( const char * left, const char * right, size_t len )
   {
     return memcmp( left, right, len ); // more efficient than the general loop above
   }
  // other functions
};

// specialise also for wchar_t
```